# How to simplify code

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
class MySuperClass : UIViewController {
    var model: ModelA!
}

class ModelA {
    var aBool = true
}

class ModelB: ModelA {
    var boolBelongsToB = true
}

class MySubclass: MySuperclass {
    func testFunction() {
        let theBool = (model as! ModelB).boolBelongsToB // Simplify this
    }
}

var aSubclass = MySubclass()
var aModelB = ModelB()
aSubclass.model = aModelB
```

What I want to do is simplify having to use the code `(model as! ModelB)` everytime I want to access my model in MySubclass. How can I do this?

Comment: This is a bit confusing, could you please provide more code so we can get a better understanding the relation between each class. Also, are you using the same variable name?

Comment: @valcanaia Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a computed property in your subclass Y which returns the correct type. Like

```
var modelB: ModelB {get { return model as! ModelB }}
```

Instead of getting it then as "(model as! ModelB)" you can just get it as "modelB".